# Dystopian movie about the slums vs rich neighbourhoods (similair to Elysium)

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I have vague memories about this movie being **filled with action**, **big guns** and a lot of **jumping on rooftops** in the slums of a post-apocalyptic/post government-crash movie. The only thing separating the slums and the rich people were some wall or something like that.

I think the movie is relatively new like late 90's or early 2000.

TIA

Comment: I feel like this describes a lot of dystopia movies, as half of dystopia are utopian but not.  And the other half are dystopia because of the great divide in power/wealth between the rich and the poor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely [Banlieue 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_13) (usually titled District B13 in English releases), a 2004 French film about residents of an impoverished residential area outside Paris fighting against gangsters and the corrupt government that has isolated their home from the outside world (as in your memory, this is done with a massive wall). The emphasis of jumping on rooftops is because the main cast are notable traceurs (parkour athletes), and most of the film's stunts were performed live without wires or special effects.

There's also a sequel, which didn't diverge far from the original, but it wasn't released until 2009. So since you're looking for an early-00s film, the first in the series is likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a society so strictly divided between the very rich and the very poor reminds me of [Freejack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freejack), even if this concept is in the background, rather than the main theme.
The movie also features a lot of chases and action, but it is an early '90s movie, so maybe it is a bit too old to be the movie you're referring to.

> In 2009, the super-wealthy achieve immortality by hiring "bonejackers", mercenaries equipped with time travel devices, to snatch people from the past, just prior to the moment of their deaths, for use as substitute bodies. Those who escape are known as "freejacks" and are considered less than human under the law. In this dystopian future, most people suffer from poor physical health as a result of rampant drug use and environmental pollution, making them unattractive as replacement bodies.

And about the chase part

> Alex spends much time escaping the clutches of Victor, a ruthless pursuer who nevertheless lives by a code of honor,